# Why does an object from my Amazon S3 bucket load on my pc browser, but not the browser in my iphone browser?

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, mp4

When I uploaded my mp4 to my Amazon S3 Bucket I allowed public access through my permissions.  The mp4 loads perfectly fine in my pc browser, but when I try to pull it up on my iphone it does not seem to be reading the S3 object correctly.

The object url is: https://numeros1422.s3.amazonaws.com/Black+on+white.mp4

That url pulls up a video on pc but has issues when pulling up on iphone.

Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: What exactly is the issue? What do you mean by "Doesn't seem to be reading correctly"?

Comment: I looked into it a bit further, the object url does not compile in the browser for any iphone lower than the 11pro.  On the contrary, the object url compiles on any pc browser perfectly fine.

Comment: What do you mean by "the object url does not compile"?

Comment: Is there some dedicated AWS streaming service involved? Like, it streams you a video of different quality and compression in regards of the device and connection? I'd maybe contact AWS support.

Comment: @jarmod the url I provided will play in the pc browser, but it does not play for Iphones lower than the Iphone 11 pro.

Comment: @DanielW. No there isn't any AWS streaming service involved.  It does seem like it's something that I may have to get some help from AWS support.

Answer (score 0):

Amazon S3 serves the content of the object the same regardless of which browser is used.

However, how the `mp4` file is interpreted will depend upon the browser being used. Some browsers might choose to display it, some might choose to download it. It might also be a factor of the memory available on the particular device.

Typically, mp4 files are not served simply as a web page. Instead, they are referenced in the HTML.

Here's an example from [w3schools - HTML Video](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp):

```html
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

This tells the browser to display a video within an HTML page.